# How to enable Cognos single sign on?

Tags: single-sign-on, cognos

What are the steps which I need to follow to enable single sign-on (Active Directory) for Cognos 10?

We are using IIS and the platform is Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: What specific problems did you face after following the steps stated on [IBM KB](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_10.2.2/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_rtm_wb.10.2.2.doc/t_config_sso.html)?

Comment: The above hyperlink directs me to Cognos Real Time monitoring RTM. I would like to know the steps to be followed to enable SSO in IIS.